# Alternative ways to export tbl_summary as png in R

Tags: r

I am trying to export my tbl_summary from R as a png file. I've tried

```
gt::gtsave(as_gt(demtable),file="demographic_table.png")
```

It comes up with the error

```
PhantomJS not found. You can install it with webshot::install_phantomjs()
```

However I am unable to execute this command (probably as I am working with data within a safe haven and R cannot connect to the internet)

Therefore I am wondering if there is any other ways to export this type of table

Comment: The most manual solution is export the data as a csv using `write.csv(demtable, 'demographic_table.csv', row.names=FALSE)`, open csv in Excel, do all the formatting you desire, and screengrab. There is a package called `rpivotTable` which creates nice tables in the html viewer, but I'm assuming you don't have that installed and can't since you're in an offline environment.

Comment: Hi, I've tried this and the error comes up as 'cannot coerce class c("tbl_summary", "gtsummary")' to a data.frame

Comment: If you give more details on how/where you need to use the table, I can likely give guidance on the best way to export without PhantomJS.

When you need to, you can convert a gtsummary table to a data frame with `as_tibble(demtable)`. You could then write it to CSV if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Below a possible solution.

You could try the `dfSummary` function from `library(summarytools)`

```
dfSummary(data_1)
```

The output file written is:

```
C:\Users\EarlMascetti\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIJ7JC4\file970319bdcd.html
```

The summary is: [image]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opening it in a new window and when right clicking could save it in excel